list of users who are online - Flask Gunicorn Gevent
I have a Flask application (for user authentication I use flask-login, flask-session). I use gunicorn with gevent and flask_socketio to run it.
I have a task to display a list of users who are online at a certain moment. I don't understand how to connect Flask with requests to gunicorn
gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker --bind 127.0.0.1:$port app:app
I'm new to Flask programming
I would be grateful for any advice

I store the sid and user information data through Redis, and then enter the online room through the user join_room. By obtaining the sid in the rooms, I reverse check the user information
Namespace is the specified space data is the room name
def all_room_user(namespace,data):
#获取指定路径下的指定房间内的所有用户信息
request_sokcetio=flask.current_app.extensions['socketio'].server
r = []
if namespace not in request_sokcetio.manager.rooms:
    return r
if data in request_sokcetio.manager.rooms[namespace]:
    user_info=request_sokcetio.manager.rooms[namespace][data]

    for room_name, room in user_info.items():
        r.append(room_name)
return r

